# Mainnet – How to fix a frozen DB syncing?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, blockchain, cardano-db-sync

I've been trying to sync with the Cardano blockchain in order to use CLI wallet on macOS Big Sur 11.6. But syncing is frozen at ***epoch 289*** on ***block 6,236,059***.

```
cardano-cli query tip --mainnet

{
    "epoch": 289,
    "hash": "e72579ff89dc9ed325b723a33624b596c08141c7bd573ecfff56a1f7229e4d09",
    "slot": 39916796,
    "block": 6236059,
    "era": "Mary"
}
```

Terminal says there are two errors. I tried to sync 2 times from scratch. It's all the same.

```
[xcode:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:67] [2021-09-26 10:46:25.44 UTC] 
Domain: "relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io" 
Application Exception: 52.58.171.193:3001 
MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: 
resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"

[xcode:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:52] [2021-09-26 10:46:25.44 UTC] 
IP 52.58.171.193:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer 
(Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError (
                                   MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: 
resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"))) 20s 20s
```

**What should I do to fix it**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey mate sorry I didn't see this earlier. As per your output logs, you are currently running Cardano-node correctly however, you are using the wrong version. Your current version is not the latest.

Luckily, not much needs to be done, you just need to recompile the new version in a new folder. Make sure you do this with DB Sync also. Development on Cardano will require frequent updates for next 6 months but it will be worth it (has been for me so far).

Your data may remain intact (wasn't so lucky myself) but I ended up needing to manually copy over the binaries to their locations so be prepared to search /opt AND /usr directories to find the files your looking to replace.

A clever search of your currently running instance on Linux, I use:

ps aux | grep cardano

To find any related processes and using its pid, you should be able to easily find the path of the executable